# Python : how put this char \ in the end of string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to do this :

```
file_name = 'file'
link_name = 'rep\' + file_name
print(link_name)
```

But I get this error message :

```
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `\` you have to use `\\`

```py
file_name = 'file'
link_name = 'rep\\' + file_name
print(link_name)
```

or if you really, really want a backslash use this:

```py
file_name = 'file'
link_name = 'rep' + chr(92) + file_name
print(link_name)
```